# How can I install dappsys in ubuntu

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, dapple

I already have dapple , how can i install dappsys ?

follow this dapple documentation to install dapple

https://dapple.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

From the [Dappsys README](https://github.com/dapphub/dappsys):

> Dappsys components are exposed as ethpm packages.

To use `ethpm` packages directly, a given tool has to support [ERC190](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/190) (Ethereum Smart Contract Packaging Specification). Dapple doesn't yet support this - [Truffle and Populus](https://www.ethpm.com/registry) do.

You could just manually install the Dappsys contract code from [Github](https://github.com/dapphub/dappsys).